# How to integrate payumoney payment gateway in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, gateway, payumoney

I'm trying to integrate Pay U Money payment gateway in my client site. My client provided me the login details of Pay U Money. site is built in JOOMLA.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried instruction given on Pay U Money but unable to integrate with Joomla .....I am not quite familiar with Joomla.

Comment: Please edit your post include a link to the instructions from the company, and a sample of what you've tried.

Comment: I used Below mentioned instruction........... https://www.payumoney.com/websiteintegration.html

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a **PayUmoney Payment Gateway** for my client in Joomla!. 
1. Create a custom page in Joomla!
2. Add `PayUmoney` button provided by PayUmoney
3. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no module available. I downloaded the plugin. it doesn't allow me to modify anything. We need module to integrate with pages.

Comment: you're sending me on an sudoko expedition... which AES you're using to decipher your answer? In short, it makes no sense at all unless you bring context to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Login to PayuMoney with your account.
Click on Other Tools
Click on WEBFRONT and create the WEBFRONT page
Add that link to your web page link or button.
No need to even have any SSL certificate also to your site.